# Where to get background sample images for haar training?

Tags: opencv, training-data

I need collection of sample images (negative images, or also called background images)
for haar training using opencv. It is written that I need to have a lot of them. About 5000 or 10000. Do you know where to get them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This [site](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) have some haar negatives from various databases. You can download by svn: `svn co http://tutorial-haartraining.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/data/negatives/`

UPDATE: It is possible that the repository died, so you can go to GitHub. I found one that was exported automatically from google code [here](https://github.com/sonots/tutorial-haartraining/tree/master/data/negatives).

Comment: Ooops, I only saw now that this question were asked 1 year ago. Sorry! I'm new here...

Comment: it doesn't matter as long as you answering it right. it may help other people like me who need it now.

Comment: this repository died.

Comment: You can go to github, I found one that was exported from google code [here](https://github.com/sonots/tutorial-haartraining/tree/master/data/negatives)

Answer (score 3):

you can find it anywhere especially in google.. negative images are just images that does not contain your positive images/samples which is the object of interest.. anything that doesn't contain your object of interest can be a negative samples..