# Where to get background/negative sample images for haar training?

Tags: image-processing, classification, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I need a collection of sample images to train a Haar-based classifier for plate detection.
I know this question has been asked already, but the source on googlecode is dead.

http://tutorial-haartraining.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/data/negatives/

[Where to get background sample images for haar training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193014/where-to-get-background-sample-images-for-haar-training)

[Where to get negative sample images for Haar training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429150/where-to-get-negative-sample-images-for-haar-training)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this one?
https://github.com/handaga/tutorial-haartraining/tree/master/data/negatives

It says

> Automatically exported from code.google.com/p/tutorial-haartraining

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite old but for those of you who are Reading this and want to know more about how to get more negative and positive images, I suggest you check out [Image Net](http://image-net.org/) and also [This](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/) to know how to use it.

Happy Training.